# Instructions on logging into svn

Tags: macos, svn

I am a new user of Subversion and need to log into a file of a coauthor to start creating some text documents. After installing SVN and watching some tutorials I realised that there are no quick instructions that I could find on how to log in to a file in a university website that is already created by someone else-although there were plenty of online instructions on how to create your own file.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean by " how to log in to a file in a university website"?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about Subversion is here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com.

You can skip right to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html for a quick introduction.

You'll need to find out the url for your repository to use svn commands to copy out files and commit changes.